# Why is Ivy unable to resolve spring-test dependency that is visible in my web browser?

Tags: ivy, dependency-management

I have an ivy.xml that can successfully resolve all of its dependencies, except the following one.

```
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-test" rev="3.0.2.RELEASE" force="true" conf="compile->test"/>
```

My ivysettings.xml has the following resolver:

```
<ibiblio name="maven" m2compatible="true" root="http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/"  />
```

When I attempt to resolve dependencies, I receive the following error message:

```
Server access Error: Connection refused: connect url=http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-test/3.0.2.RELEASE/spring-test-3.0.2.RELEASE.pom
```

However, when I navigate to that URL in my browser, I've can see the .pom and the .jars. What could be preventing Ivy from resolving this dependency?

Comment: Yes. But I'm able to retrieve all other spring-* dependencies without issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly sounds like a proxy issue.

Any chance the other spring dependencies were previously downloaded (for example when you were working at home) and were retrieved from the ivy cache?

To configure ANT to use the same proxy as your web browser you need to read [this web page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/proxy.html). In summary, set the following environment variables with the appropriate values:

```
export ANT_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080"
```

Comment: Yeah. That's the route I ended up going. But it seems like this only works if Ivy's resolve and retrieve are run from within an Ant task. If I use the Eclipse plugin, or try to run from the command line, it doesn't seem to pick that up.

Comment: Eclipse has it's own mechanism for setting the HTTP proxy. http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t45492.html. If this answer has helped, please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with 3.0.5 but I don't use a proxy. The fix for me was to add the spring repo for releases as I only had external in my ivysettings.xml.

**ivysettings.xml**

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="chain"/>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="chain">
            <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
            <ibiblio name="springsource-external" m2compatible="true" root="http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external"/>
            <ibiblio name="springsource-release" m2compatible="true" root="http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```